# What does forName() method in the Class class do, when loading jdbc:odbc driver?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, odbc, driver

I am learning to enable my Java application to communicate with a MS Access database.

I am unsure of one method, the Class.forName() method. The parameter I pass is "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver", which loads the jdbc:odbc bridge for accessing a database.

What does the Class.forName() do exactly and why is it needed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to add on here, it's not strictly *needed*.  You can achieve the same effect with `DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver())` assuming that the driver has a constructor you can use.

Comment: Note that for JDBC 4.0+ drivers (since Java SE 6) this is no longer necessary: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

Comment: @IanMcLaird Most drivers will call `DriverManager.registerDriver` themselves when the class is loaded; an end-user almost never has to call registerdriver himself; in this example `new Driver()` itself would have loaded and registered the driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Class.forName()` causes ClassLoader to load the class into memory. JDBC driver classes have static initializers that register them with DriverManager for further use. After you use `Class.forName()`, and use `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:*", database, username, password)`, the `jdbc:` is already loaded in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName()` is used for loading class dynamically. For example you called `Class.forName("z")` , this will cause the class z to get initialized and corresponding object will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName() uses reflection to load the class of the given name. It returns a Class object. See [this](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17).

In your case, it allows you to load a specific driver at runtime, without hardcoding the driver type. You just have to pass the driver name as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It uses `reflection` to instantiate `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` class, using the class name in String format.

This makes your code **`Driver` class independent** and allows you to pass the driver class name externally as a String parameter (which is standard behavior as we pass the connection details through configuration).